# Proxied requests do not get carried out

Tags: python, web, proxy, request

I'm experimenting with proxy servers, I want to create a Bot who connects every few minutes to my web server and scrapes a file (namely the index.html) for changes.

I tried to apply things I learned in some multihour python tutorials and got to the result to make it a bit more funny I could use random proxies.

So I wrote down this method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import choice

#here I get the proxy from a proxylist due processing a table embedded in html with beautifulSoup
def get_proxy():
    print("bin in get_proxy")
    proxyDomain = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    r = requests.get(proxyDomain)

    print("bin in mache gerade suppe")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'proxylisttable'})

#this part works
    #print(table.get_text)

    print("zeit für die Liste")
    ipAddresses = []

    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        columns = row.findAll('td')
        try:
            ipAddresses.append("https://"+str(columns[0].get_text()) + ":" + str(columns[1].get_text()))

            #ipList.append(str(columns[0].get_text()) + ":" + str(columns[1].get_text()))
        except:
            pass
#here the program returns one random IP Address from the list 
   return choice(ipAddresses)



# return 'https://': + choice(iplist)

def proxy_request(request_type, url, **kwargs):
    print("bin in proxy_request")
    while 1:
        try:
            proxy = get_proxy()
            print("heute verwenden wir {}".format(proxy))
#so until this line everything seems to work as i want it to do

#now the next line should do the proxied request and at the end of the loop it should return some html text....
            r = requests.request(request_type, url, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, **kwargs)
            break
        except:
            pass
    return r


def launch():
    print("bin in launch")
    r = proxy_request('get', 'https://mysliwje.uber.space.')

### but this text never arrives here - maybe the request is going to be carried out the wrong way
###does anybody got a idea how to solve that program so that it may work?
    print(r.text)


launch()
```

as i explained in the code section before, the code works nice, it picks some random ip of a random ip list and prints it even to the cli. the next step all of the sudden seems to be carried out the wrong way, because the tools is running back scraping a new ip address 
and another 
and another 
and another
and another...
of a list that seems to be updated every few minutes....
so i ask myself what is happening, why i dont see the simple html code of my indexpage?

Anybody any Idea?

Thanxx

Comment: Is your code in a loop all the time?
while 1:

Comment: While gets a break after printing out the fitting result I thought as the break statement implies

Comment: Hey there, I'm sitting again on my program and as time goes by somebody fixed up my misspellings but I don't get it what exactly in my program is messing up the output :/ would you please help me